# Cocoa App Preferences (Views in one XIB?)

Tags: cocoa, xib, nsview, nib, nsviewcontroller

I was just wondering if when I create my App Preferences if it's better to either have all of the views in one XIB and have:

```c
-(id)initWithSelectedToolBarItem: (NSToolBarItem*)toolBarItem{
    self = [self initWithNibName: [[toolBarItem label] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] bundle:nil];
    // init code in initWithNibName...
    if (!self) return nil;
        return self;
}
```

Or just go the conventional route and have separate nibs etc...?

The reason why I ask is because so far the project is getting huge (as in the number of separate files) and I'm trying to shave it down a bit.

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Cheers in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferences window code has each of the views, which are switched using a toolbar like yours, in a single  `.xib` with an outlet to each `NSView` instance from the preference window controller:

```
@interface PreferenceController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate, NSToolbarDelegate, FontChooserViewDelegate> {
    // Main window
    IBOutlet NSToolbar *_toolbar;
    IBOutlet NSBox *_box;
    IBOutlet NSButton *_restoreDefaultsButton;
    IBOutlet NSView *_generalPrefsView;
    IBOutlet NSView *_boardPrefsView;
    IBOutlet NSView *_movesPrefsView;

    // Other outlets to individual UI elements on some of the views.
}
```

So I'd say "Yes", you should do that, however there is no need to subclass the `NSView` and hence no need to worry about special initialisation.

**EDIT** Actually, that's a lie; one of the views is subclassed but uses standard `NSView` initialisation (`initWithFrame` and `awakeFromNib`).

Comment: Thanks :) What I wound up doing was writing a protocolled subclass of NSViewController. It was quite a bit more work, but now I've goat reusable module I can just drop in place :) Thanks or the tip :)

Comment: @AdrianSluyters Ah OK, but why `NSViewController`?

Comment: The code I ended up referring to was this: https://github.com/heardrwt/RHPreferences

Pretty well written, and was very impressed. It's a bit OTT for what I needed but it pretty much answered all of my questions in one swoop :) Hope it helps others too!